# Laravel Where Not Equal To x 2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model which I'm trying to query using eloquent.

In my table I have the following columns.

```
Order ID
Invoiced -> default(0)
Delivered -> default(0)
```

I want to query this table and only show orders where not invoiced and not delivered but can show orders where are delivered but not invoiced or are invoiced but not delivered.

How would I do this in Eloquent?

Here's my code:

```
$orders = Order::where('delivered', '<>', 1)->where('invoiced', '<>', 1)->get();
```

The above works however when I update an order to delivered but the invoice is still outstanding this removes the order from the list.

I want to exclude all orders where the are complete i.e. delivered and invoiced.

Comment: Becuase that's an `OR` , not `AND`

Comment: I can't replace orWhere with ANDWhere as this isn't a function apparently. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ANDWhere()

Comment: Just another `WHERE` , not `ANDWHERE`

Comment: `where()` is an AND Where

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this:

```
$orders = Order::where('delivered', '<>', 1)->where('invoiced', '<>', 1)->get();
```

**Update**

Did not test, but try this for 'should show where orders are delivered not invoiced, or invoiced but not delivered':

```
$orders = Order::where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('delivered', 1)->where('invoiced', '<>', 1);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('delivered', '<>', 1)->where('invoiced', 1);
        })->get();
```

Comment: This is great however it removes orders where they have been delivered. This should output orders where not delivered, where not invoiced but should show where orders are delivered not invoiced, or invoiced but not delivered.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to tell, but this code does exactly this: `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Invoiced <> 1 AND Delivered <> 1` (SQL query from your question).

Comment: @Wolrab - the logic that you've just specified in your comment here is not the same as the logic you specified in your question

Comment: Sorry @MarkBaker your right. let me update question.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyMezenin this worked better however it still shows orders where invoiced is 1 and delivered is 1.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin sorted it, it was an issue with my code, your answer is correct!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might solve your problem

```
.. whereNotIn( 'id', [$user_id])->get();
```

in this solution, you can choose a range of id s or one id.